# Loopback Facebook Account Link with passport

Tags: facebook, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm working with an application and I'm using the loopback tokens to handle the user session. I need to implement a facebook account linking, where a user that already is logged in can link the account in our system with the account from Facebook. I tried with the facebook link of [loopback-component-passport](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Third-party-login-using-Passport.html) but can not recognize the user that started the linking process. I red about this and says that should be using cookies/session instead the loopback tokens.

Anyone here has faced similar issues? Is there a way to implement the facebook linking using the plugin without session? Any work around to make this work?.

Any Help is welcomed!